# How would an aquatic race of humanoids move as flawlessly as humans do on land?

Tags: internal-consistency, underwater, science-in-society

Assuming the same rules for physics apply to this world as they do for our own, how would a humanoid race that lives at the bottom of the sea be able to walk around like humans do on land? What kind of evolutionary trait would provide this phenomenon?

It should also be noted that they cannot swim unless on the surface of a body of water, and a select few can manage travel by land, although not for an extended period of time.

Comment: The humanoid would need legs to walk on terrain and a a more flexible spine and stronger back muscles  to swim faster

Comment: Humans don'y move flawlessly on land ^.^ that's why we fall :P

Comment: kids and old people fall* Unless you are in a low quality horror movie you aren't going to see many people falling down.

Comment: Evolution *will* make sure they don't walk on the seabed, but dive. Unless they have some mean deiety like you, that forbids it.

Comment: Taste like crab, talk like people. Crab people.

Comment: @Karl There are some animals that live on the ocean floor but are either unable to swim or can do so only infrequently.  But since swimming, like flying, is so useful, and unlike flying is easy from a biological perspective, there needs to be a good reason why *not* to swim.  Most bottom-dwellers are at the bottom of the food chain where they feed on detritus and hide from enemies in the sand or rocks, so there's no reason for them to swim, and so they increase their overall density (developing shells, etc.) to be tougher instead.  It's hard to think a humanoid would live like this though.

Comment: The syntax of this question is a bit ambiguous.  Are these creatures who walk around like humans *on the sea floor* instead of swimming, or are they aquatic, swimming humans who can walk around like humans *on land*?  I think you mean the first, but some answers are interpreting it as the second.  Perhaps edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two big barriers to walking around on the sea bed like we do on land. Ignoring the obvious one about breathing, which we assume is solved, the others are:

1. bouyancy
2. drag

Bouyancy means that any humans who tried walking on the sea bottom would end up bouncing along like a moonwalk<sup>1</sup>, or just floating up. They also wouldn't be able to get any traction to propel themselves forward, which means they would be very slow. You see this any time someone actually in the water tries to walk.

A human body in water also has much more drag than one in air, which means that even if you had the same forces propelling you forward, and you didn't tend to float, a humanoid would move much slower than on land. Combined with the above they would be *extremely* slow.That would make a humanoid ancestor easy prey for anything that was more streamlined and had 3D movement in the water. A shark would make easy pickings of one.

Fortunately the answer to both of these is the same - much more weight (or technically density). A bottom-walking humanoid would have to be much, much heavier than a human, They would also have to be proportionately stronger to overcome the drag.

Given that they are going to have to be slow, and wanting to avoid being prey for the local sharkoids, this leads the humanoid ancestors down the road of armour. If you have to be slow and heavy, you may as well be well protected. This is the direction all bottom-walking life has gone on earth.

So coming back to the present day intelligent speices, since the humanoids are already heavy and well-armoured, and given that projectile weapons work very badly underwater (drag again) your humanoids are perfectly set up for some awesome sword versus shark battles - the underwater equivalent of knight versus dragon. At least you could if only your humanoids could find a way to kindle fire, and thus do metallurgy, underwater. But that's a subject for another question.

*1. Armstrong, not Jackson.*

Answer (score 4):

Humans can already [swim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAIRWXYX3s8) with one of the most effective movements in nature,an aquatic humanoid would not need a tail even if it could be useful, but bigger levels of red cells in the blood,stronger back muscles and a more flexible spine and maybe larger feet would be just enough  to swim as fast as a fish.

No more changes are needed to make an underwater humanoid, therefore your humanoid would have no problem on ground has being just a person with a more sportive anatomy.

If however you want to take out the legs and replace them with a tail, then your humanoids would need to learn how to crawl like a snake, this movement is both effective on water as on land however the difference between legs and a tail is that with a tail you might be faster but also have less stamina which would turn those humanoids in exactly the opposite of humans, as we are natural endurance runners and not sprinters.

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, we are talking about a humanoid race, not humans in this situation. This gives us slightly more leeway.

Since this race would be living and breathing underwater they would not have the problem of floating since they would be inhaling the same substance in which they lived.

This race would also be able to walk very easily on land if they had the ability to leave the water, because we as humans experience pressure and drag on our bodies as well, just on a much smaller scale. Since these humanoid creatures are born under the water and grow up walking in a substance much heavier and denser than air, they would have almost super human capabilities if they had the capability to leave their home. This is because air puts much less pressure and drag on a body than that of water.

As I said more than once however, your next problem is their ability to leave the water.

Answer (score 2):

Humanoids living and walking along the bottom of an earth-like planet would have to put up with extreme pressure, wouldn't they?  So, first of all they'd probably be shaped differently - shorter, squatter, beefy-er, etc.  Their bone structure would likely be more dense.

Given that they could breathe air, they might find walking on the surface of the earth a little like flying - definitely liberating.